# How to set the dropdown scrollbar at top whenever the dropdown is opened

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angularjs

I have a custom made drag and drop multi select dropdown. Its has only the unique control id for dropdown. First time when we open the dropdown the scroll is at the top. Next when we go down and close the dropdown. Next time when its opened, the scroll bar is at the same position(down).

How to set the scroll bar at the top whenever it is opened. Any css property will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For better understanding Can you please paste your code here. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the code since its a proprietary software. Multi select dropdown is a drag and drop option.

Comment: You don't need to post all your code, just a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have used overflow correctly, you can use overflow-y for vertical scrollbar and overflow-x for horizontal scrollbar.

Ex:

.dropMenu{

overflow-y:auto;

}

/* If there's any horizontal scrollbar it will be hidden automatically and the vertical one will stay*/